# Major Compaction on ScyllaDB

Tags: database, cassandra, scylla, tombstone

Simple query:- I deleted data on Scylla with gc_grace_seconds 10 days. Scylla created tombstones and waiting for gc_grace_seconds expiration.

Now, I have run major compaction on 2nd day after deletion(8 days still remaining for gc_grace_seconds expiration).

1)What compaction will do? It will consider all tombstones and clear which deleted 2 days before or not?

2) I should change gc_grace_seconds=0 before running major compaction?

Please help

Thanks in Advance.

Answer (score 2):

1) At least in Cassandra (no idea about scylla) it would not purge the tombstones until gc_grace_seconds has passed. Thats what the grace seconds is for - to tell the database to keep tombstones for at least that long.

2) You can if you really want to purge them. With 0 gc grace it also means hints wont be stored in Cassandra so might want to set to `1` instead unless you are Ok with decreased durability of newly written data. Would also need to make sure repairs have completed since your data was written or the data the tombstones purge may (unlikely though) be resurrected. If set `only_purge_repaired_tombstones` would prevent the purging even past the gc grace if data hasnt been repaired (I would recommend setting that for what its worth)

Comment: Thanks. But still I have a doubt that if I will change gc_grace_sceonds to 0 then it will applicable coming deletes or already deleted with gc_grace_seconds 10  or both?. Also, from above comment major compaction will not clear tombstone always bounded by gc_grace_second  right?

Comment: @LetsNoSQL Tombstones only contain information about when the deletion occurred. When deciding about expiry, compaction always takes gc_grace_seconds from the schema when it starts. So changing gc_grace_seconds will also affect expiry of already existing tombstones.

Comment: @LetsNoSQL Scylla doesn't yet support "only_purge_repaired_tombstones". See https://github.com/scylladb/scylla/issues/3560. I think currently major compaction would not leave any expired tombstones.

Comment: @Tomek, You mean changing gc_grace_seconds 0 will change previous tombstones expiry(Previous gc_grace_seconds 10) for that table which was deleted 2 day ago. next compaction will clear those tombstones right?

Comment: when it compacts it checks the timestamp of the tombstone and the gc grace seconds, if `timestamp + gc_grace < now` and the compaction has all the sstables that own the partition (at least sstables older than timestamp), the tombstone will be purged and not written in the new sstable. Setting it to 0 will purge it with a major compaction.

Comment: @LetsNoSQL Yes, changing gc_grace_seconds to 0 and then compacting should purge all tombstones. Note that if you delete data using CQL, doing so is unsafe, since replication failure may lead to data resurrection.

Comment: RF failure will not result in data resurrection unless you 1) dont have `only_purge_repaired_tombstones` set and 2) dont repair within gc_grace_seconds. Even then the RF failure has to be combined with a durability failure of hints corrupted or not flushed with crash and never read with > CL.ONE.